# The Tomcat installation directory is not valid. It is missing expected file or folder tcruntime-ctl.sh

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, spring-tool-suite, pivotal-tc

Even after searching too much i couldn't find any suitable answer for my problem.
I am using Spring Tool Suite and trying to create a new server but getting error as  `The specified server is not valid. The .tc-runtime-instance file is missing.`
So, I tried updating pivotal using Windows> Preferences and tried editing pivotal with new release but got the error as attached: [image]

I tried changing tomcat version from 9 to 7 too but still no success. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the server adapter for the "Pivotal tc Server" to configure your server in the IDE. This server adapter is for the Pivotal tc Server only and doesn't work with a plain Tomcat installation on your disc. For that, you should select the "Apache Tomcat" server adapter when creating a server instance in your IDE.